# PHP/HTML5 : How to Retrieve User submitted form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

i'm a beginner programmer who have to provide huge project very soon ..
i have a dynamic website
The problem is that there is an html form on it as the page which allowing the user to making his post "create.html" : write a text in the Textarea and upload an images or video too

well, i'm sure this request sounds very stupid but i'm really so confused ..
i have my own database, and **what i want to do is when the user submit his form, all of that inputs should be published on the Index page "index.html" also the " comment, like ..etc." buttons should appears bellow the post**

here is a pic for the index page and how the post should be:
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXRfq.jpg)

i need an explanation to do that more than a real codes i think, and sorry for my bad grammar i tried my best
hope you could help me :( i'm ready to pay $$

Comment: What you try ? Show some code.

Comment: It works a bit different. You don't *publish* values to a page, but you get values from the database and present them on the index.html page. The form on create.html should have an `action` attribute with a value that directs to a PHP file. That PHP file should be responsible for receiving the values from the form and putting them in the database. Now when you submit a form, you update the values in the database. When you navigate back to the index.html file, your values should be updated. Be careful with forms; all input should be validated - make sure the values are not malicious.

Comment: I am unsure if I have understood your question, but kindly check this tutorial [link](https://www.guru99.com/php-forms-handling.html). They have tried to explain the form submission well

Comment: @abhay i tried to use "action" attribute in the form tag but i don't think it's really work  :    <form id="postForm" action="index.html" method="get">

Comment: Do you genuinely want to use the `GET` method? If not use the `POST` method and try your code again

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Ayyy how brilliant you are, i got you ! Thank you so much this is what i really needed to understand. cause i know how things are connected but i didn't know how to start or use it effectively .. Thanks again 3>

Comment: @Joe_Tz Thank you Joe, i think it will help me i'll check it, Thanks